# How to store and evaluate dynamic expressions in MySQL(or any other SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, search, database-design

### Best way to store a dynamic expression in a table for each row for a searching module.

The expression is dynamic and can have multiple fields which are being compared.
I considered creating a separate column for each type of field and fattening out complex nested logic by getting all possible combinations using [dnf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) and storing them in my table. The disadvantages of doing that is for every new logic and expression, a new column has to be created which would lead to a large table which has too many NULLS in it and also adding a new column would take time & refactoring(we are talking about more than 800 columns here).
The alternate approach which I think would work better is below->
I want to discuss if there are better way to this, and if not, how can we improve and achieve the below suggested approach.

```
|  id  |                  expression                    |  diagnosis  |  
|------|------------------------------------------------|-------------|  
|   1  |`p.age>12 and p.gender==Male`                   |  diseaseA   |  
|   2  |`p.age>50 and p.bp>20`                          |  diseaseB   |  
|   3  |`p.age<20 and p.bp<20`                          |  diseaseC   |   
|   4  |`p.age<30 and p.age>20 and (p.bp<30 or p.bp>50)`|  diseaseD   |
```

I want to search in this table, for a patient p with certain properties (`age=*something*`,`bp=*something*`,etc).
The resulting rows should return all rows which satisfy the expression and also rows which partially match the expression(i.e the rows which are using properties not supplied in the search criteria).

For example for a search for patient `p(age=22,bp=15)`, the search result should be

```
|  id  |  disease    |  
|------|-------------|  
|   1  |  diseaseA   |  
|   3  |  diseaseC   |  
|   4  |  diseaseD   |
```

Since I am new to SQL, the (newbie) way I think I can do this is

1. First get all the rows(in-memory would be costly, lets discuss what is best possible way to execute the below said functionality in point 2 row-by-row)
2. Then row-by-row transform the expression to a logical executable expression(which is later executed using [eval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval)) using regex matching & replacement(I hope there is a better way than this) for the search criteria(i.e. substituting the patient details)   [in my example for the 2nd row, the expression `p.age>50 and p.bp>20` gets converted to `"22>50 && 15>20"`]
3. All the rows for which the result of transforming & executing the result was true(or partially matched) should be returned.

*The language is not an issue as I would be starting this project from scratch and can use any language*

Comment: "partially matched"?  That is a _lot_ more complex.  We need to know if that is a requirement before discussing.

Comment: By "partially matched" I mean to say if a field exists in an expression but does not exist in the query(the patient details), the result of that expression is considered true, as we don't want to loose valuable article(expression) because of lack of information from patients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer for MySQL. 
First of all, you'll have to write all of your sql code inside sql procedure.
Generally you are interestedin dynamic SQL
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html
So a straight-forward approach is to open a a cursor for your table with expressions and for each expression replace p.age with it's actual value and then execute dynamic SQL. (select 22 > 50 and 15 > 20)

Another approach is to loop through expression table (open cursor for it) and as you probably have patient id (not only it's field values) just generate normal sql that selects from patient table (select patient_id from patients where [expression_from_expression_table] and patient_id = [your_known_patient_id])

And the third one that I can imagine is generating a big single query from whole expression table

```
select group_concat(concat('if(', expression, ',"', diagnosis, '", "") as ', diagnosis) separator ',') from expressions into somevar;
```

and then doing replace of p.* with actual values and executing second query:

```
set somevar = replace(somevar, 'p.age', '15');
...
@qry = concat('select ', somevar);
PREPARE qry FROM @qry;
EXECUTE qry;
```

The third approach is fastest to my mind but will require aditional work on client as you will recieve diagnosis as columns, not as rows. 
But hope you get the general idea.